# kafka API for Reading kafka messages in a Group from topic with same partition key

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have 5 million of messages in internal  Kafka Topic.

```
1 million  message with Partition key  -1234-Messge1
1 million  message with Partition key  -2345-Messge2
1 million  message with Partition key  -5678-Messge3
1 million  message with Partition key  -6789-Messge4
1 million  message with Partition key  -6565-Messge5
```

I have to join messages having **same Partitionkey**  as part of single message and send to an consumer Topic [Eg: For key **1234-Messge1**,consumer should receive single message instead of 1 million message]

Is there any Kafka API available at kafka end ,using which I can read all the messages having same Partition key in a group instead of reading single message at a time like traditional spring boot kafka Listener.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, polling a kafka topic will always require "reading single message at a time". Only after reading "one at a time", would you be able to "group/filter by key" (your question is not about the Connect API)

Comment: Hi  
@OneCricketeer,so u r saying no Kafka provided API is there that can read messages having partition key in group?Anything available with kafkaConnect to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Connect is built on the Consumer API, but it always calls `subscribe` to read all partitions. From a consumer, you can `assign` a topic partition, and read all data from **one partition**. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Regarding Spring-Kafka, you can add `topicPartitions` property to `@KafkaListener` to read from one or many partitions rather than all.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer .Ya quite similar..But I know only the messagekey.Can I control that my consumer will read only messages having specific key form that partition?

Comment: If you have multiple keys in the same partition, you would still need to read all messages in one partition, then use `if` statements to look for a specific key

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka Streams, you can `filter` on a specific ***record*** key, but this will read all the partitions. You can also `groupByKey` if you wanted the same logic for all keys, and can query all values from a `KTable`, for example.

If you already know (or can compute) the topic partition, you can `assign` (or use  `@KafkaListener` property [`topicPartitions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#topicPartitions())) to make a `Consumer` read one-to-many `TopicPartition`. This will still read all records for that partition, and if you have multiple keys, you would need `if (record.key().equals(partitionKey))`

Answer (score 1):

Not really, as Kafka does not provide key-driven API. In the end (whether you use KafkaConsumer directly or Streams), you are going to read all records from  the partitions you want.

If you know what partition(s) your records are in, then you might set up the consumers to read from these partition(s).

However please remember you might have been impacted by situation like increasing number of partition in a topic (what changes a hash function, unless you use stable hashing partitioner).